# OpenERP, error when preview pentaho report

Tags: pentaho

I had just reinstalled OpenERP and Pentaho. When I preview Pentaho report from OpenERP, it shows the message below. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

The error message is :

> class 'xmlrpclib.ProtocolError', ProtocolError for
>   localhost:8080/pentaho-reports-for-openerp: 302 Moved Temporarily,
>   traceback object at 0x0514CD78

Comment: Edit your question, don't post it in comments

Comment: Beloo, I had edited my question. Could anyone gave me a solution?